# Gallery widget for Blogger showing all images of the current post

Tags: widget, gallery, blogger

For my blog (in Blogger) I'm looking for a gallery widget, which shows all images of the currently selected post. Ideally the images are shown in a slider or carousel. But I'd already be happy, with a simple list of the images.

Does anyone have the code for such a widget? I haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created [a widget](https://www.dte.web.id/2018/09/widget-komik-untuk-blogger.html) to convert **Blogger** post content into dynamic web comics. Someday I will make a similar widget in the form of an image gallery so that it will becomes more universal.

**Demo:** https://dte-project.github.io/blogger/comic.html